# How to use CalibratedClassifierCV for models without predict_proba or decision_function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to calibrate my model outputs using `CalibratedClassifierCV()` to create a better fitting calibration curve. As I understand for tree based models, neural networks, outputs have to be calibrated using this method for optimal performance. However when I try to do that, it is raising an error.

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

pipe_dtr = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                           ('clf', DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=62))])
params_dtr = {
    'clf__max_depth' : np.arange(1,100,5),
    'clf__min_samples_leaf' : [0.01, 0.1, 1]
}
gs_dtr = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe_dtr, 
                    param_distributions=params_dtr,
                    n_iter=25,
                    scoring='roc_auc',
                    cv=5)

gs_dtr.fit(X_train, y_train)

calib_pipe_dtr = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), 
                                ('calibrator', CalibratedClassifierCV(gs_dtr.best_estimator_, cv='prefit'))])
calib_pipe_dtr.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

This is raising the following error

> RuntimeError: classifier has no decision_function or predict_proba
>   method.

How do I solve this problem.. Kindly opine. Thank you

Comment: None of the regressor models will have `decision_function` or `predict_proba`, use classifier model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regressor model should be used for CalibratedClassifierCV. If you are solving a classification problem, then use DecisionTreeClassifier.

Working example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y= load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, stratify=y)
pipe_dtr = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', StandardScaler()),
                           ('clf', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=62))])
params_dtr = {
    'clf__max_depth' : np.arange(1,100,5),
    'clf__min_samples_leaf' : [0.01, 0.1, 1]
}
gs_dtr = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipe_dtr, 
                    param_distributions=params_dtr,
                    n_iter=25,
                    scoring='accuracy',
                    cv=5)

gs_dtr.fit(X_train, y_train)

calib_pipe_dtr = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', StandardScaler()), 
                                ('calibrator', CalibratedClassifierCV(gs_dtr.best_estimator_, cv='prefit'))])
calib_pipe_dtr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Also, as a follow up, how to use CalibratedClassifierCV to calibrate outputs of Neural Networks? It gives me an error saying 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'classes_'

Comment: are you using `kerasClassifier`?

Comment: No.. I was not using ```kerasClassifier```. That should solve the problem.. Thank you so much again..